# Retrieving the data from the fields of a table in AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

i would like to know this thing.. "if we have modified the values in the tables for ten times or something can we retrieve the values which i have inserted for the first time 2nd time and so on ..can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see them, you could use the [Database Log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362089.aspx)  functionality